# Using Sed and Find with Grep Linux

Tags: sed, archlinux

I am writing a script that will saech for php files that contain a phrase and I would like that phrase replaced with a new one below is my little script but it is not working it searches ok but does not work with the search and replace section

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec grep -H "define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');" {} \; | xargs sed -i "define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');/define('DB_HOST', '10.0.0.1');/g"
```

can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong

many thanks

Joe

Comment: It would be good if you could provide sample data of your `php` files so that we can test at our end.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

did you forget the 's/' at the beggining of the sed expression? As in

```
sed 's/expression1/expression2/g'
```

You seem to have

```
sed 'espression1/expression2/g'
```

**Edit**

Another thing: You don't need to use `xarg` here. You can use multiple `-exec` flags - and it will to each only if all the previous succeeded:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec grep 'whatever' {} \; -exec sed -i 's/whatever/you want/g' {} \;
```

Comment: It's just on `s/` that's causing problem. Even with this correction result is mess.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec grep -l "define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');" {} \; | xargs sed -i "s/define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');/define('DB_HOST', '10.0.0.1');/g"
```

**Corrections**

- Missing `s/` in sed search and replace command
- use `grep -l` instead of `grep -H`